# Connect API Gateway custom domain to hostedZone in separate account

Tags: amazon-web-services

**If I have 3 AWS Accounts(A, B, and C), can I create a Route53 HostedZone(example.com) in account A, and route traffic to API gateways in accounts B and C(equally or based on health check) from the hostedZone in account A?**

I've tried the following:

1. Create child hosted zone in account B and C(b.example.com)
2. Create ACM Certificate and API Gateway Custom Domain in account B and C(apigw.b.example.com)
3. Add Alias RecordSet type A to account A HostedZone pointing to API gateway's domain name and hosted zone ID.

Doing this results in example.com routing to the execute-api endpoint of API gateway, which is what I want, but access is restricted because example.com isn't included in the certificate's protected domains. I'm guessing this is because the ACM certificate is local to the child account and its hosted zone(b.example.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made to get it working:

1. Get rid of child hosted zones in the API Gateway accounts
2. Create same domain name for every API Gateway(this works because they're regional).
3. Do cross account validation of ACM certificates.

So in short, yes you can do this and split everything by account. It just requires some cross account wiring for the CNAME records that validate the ACM certificates and the Alias A records that connect the API gateways to the cross account hosted zone.